# Why Some of the Sql Query Taking So much time To Execute and Some Sql Queries do not Take that

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Database Images

[image: Database Images]

I want to find the reason why It is Taking So much Time for Particularly one Query and Rest Of the Queries  are not taking too much Time to Execute on Our Sql Database

Comment: Please show the lagging query, with the tables cardinalities if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sql server first creates a execution plan for query. So when you are running first time your query it will create a execution plan for that query. Subsequent queries donot need to create execution plan. Thats why subsequent queries are running fast.

This is one of the reason that's why we create procedures because procedures creates execution plan only first time. Subsequent queries used created execution plan.